# Where are the relevant source files used when compiling a kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to find all of the source files used for the make process of building a kernel. For instance, if I compile the kernel with "make allnoconfig", where are the source files used when compiling this kind of kernel after running "make"?  I thought it'd be useful to know which files went into the kernel I'm building. That way I can study the code in them (the ones relevant to the kernel I built).

Answer (score 0):

The source files relevant to the kernel you are building can be found in the source tree directory specified by the `KERNEL_SOURCE` variable. By default, the source tree is located in the `/usr/src/linux` directory.

Within the kernel source tree, the relevant source files are organized in various directories, such as `arch` (architecture-specific code), `drivers` (device drivers), `fs` (filesystems), `kernel` (core kernel code), and many others.

But in general, I'd suggest you just read some linux kernel books :)